# In Whatsapp, when I use multiple devices and browser, are my private keys the same and shared among them?

Tags: encryption

In Whatsapp, are the same private keys used in all my devices? Is the sharing of the keys from scanning the QR code on the web browser to link to my device? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

In the original whatsapp web it only worked when your phone was online. Messages were sent with end2end encryption to the phone which decrypted them and then forwarded them in a separetly encrypted channel via their servers to your browser.

However there is now a new option to connect up to 4 devices which can recieve and send messages independently. Whatstapp assures us this just as secure and is still end-to-end encrypted.

There are essentially two ways of doing this, one is with sharing the keys and another is having other devices encrypt messages with 4 mutliple keys. It appears whatsapp are doing the latter, when sending a message the sender client is aware of all "companion devices"

Whatsapp keep updating their whitepaper explaining their encryption:
https://scontent.ftlv20-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.8562-6/309931030_1190816831854425_566987148724978105_n.pdf?_nc_cat=100&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=ae5e01&_nc_ohc=GK3jNlzDpJgAX-h9ptS&_nc_ht=scontent.ftlv20-1.fna&oh=00_AfArO5I1CbrlgAomIv_wuKwe6pnrnW_aaeyruHKNX5N_Fg&oe=636ADA36